# Jenkins pipeline script is globbing string with wildcard when it shouldn't

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple jenkins pipeline script that I have some sh code running. The important bit looks like this

```
script{
    sh "cp folderA/file.txt newFolder/"
    sh "cp -r folderB/* newFolder/"
    sh "cp folderC/\\* newFolder/"
}
```

When I look at the console output of the jenkins pipeline I see the following

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ cp folderA/file.txt newFolder/
[Pipeline] sh
+ cp -r folderB/folder1 folderB/folder2 folderB/folder3 newFolder/
[Pipeline] sh
+ cp 'folderC/*' newFolder/
cp: cannot stat 'folderC/*': No such file or director
```

I've tried various combinations of quotes and escape characters, but jenkins/groovy will either expand the filenames (as in the second example), or add quotes around the 'folderA/*' (as in the third example) which confuses sh because `folderC/` exists but `'folderC/'` does not and the copy fails. Any idea how to do this properly?

I tried using fileCopyOperation already but ran into issues because I couldn't manipulate the file paths properly. ie: I couldn't figure out how to move many files/folders like `folderA/folderB/file.txt` to `newFolder/file.txt` without it becoming `newFolder/folderA/folderB/file.txt`

Comment: What command are you trying to achive in the third example?
Did you try single-quoting the whole command?